# Imitating UITableViewControllers behavior for tableView:willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath: on UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

In my app I needed to use a `UIViewController` to control my tableView instead of a `UITableViewController` (because I needed an additional view beneath my tableView). I've implemented the view controller (and delegate and datasource) succesfully but now I need to get the right behavior on my `UITableViewCell`s when the user swipes from left to right on a cell.

The behavior needed when the user taps the edit button (display the rearrangement drag handle, and the little "-" button that makes the delete confirmation show) was pretty easy to do. I just did like this in my view controller:

```
 - (void)setEditing:(BOOL)isEditing animated:(BOOL)animated {
     [super setEditing:isEditing animated:animated]; 
     [self.tableView setEditing:isEditing animated:animated];
    }
```

But I can't figure out how to make the delete confirmation show if the user swipes from left to right on the cell. This is what I've got in my `tableView:willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:` right now:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 // Tell the cell to do its custom animations
 [[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setEditing:YES animated:YES];

 // set the viewControllers editing to YES, thus changing the editButton to a doneButton
 self.editing = YES;
}
```

With this code the editButton changes to a doneButton as it's supposed to and the cell does its animations to make room for the delete confirmation, but the delete confirmation itself doesn't show.

My question: How do I show the delete confirmation on a specified tableviewCell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself. Actually all i had to do was insert the same code from my setEditing:animated: into the tableView:willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath method.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   [super setEditing:isEditing animated:animated]; 
   [self.tableView setEditing:isEditing animated:animated];

   //Self.editing handles the done / edit button
   self.editing = YES;
}
```

That did the trick. I don't know how the tableView knows that it's only supposed to show the delete button for one cell, but it does and it works.

Comment: Note: If you want the edit button to go back to done if the user makes the delete button go away (without pressing the done button), you should just implement tableView:didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath: in which you set self.editing = NO

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you implement the method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

when this is implemented (it needs to be anyway, since this is where you handle the delete button), the swipe a row to show the delete button gesture is implemented for you automatically.

Comment: I've already implemented this method, but it doesn't display the delete button as far as i can see. This method gets called when the user taps the delete button, which the user can't since the delete button isn't displayed.